# Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{}>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to create an app using [TMDB](https://www.themoviedb.org/) using NextJS an Typescript.

I have a movies.ts file with this code:

```
export async function getTrendMovies() {
    const url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/day?language=en-US';
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer [my token]'
        }
    };

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('error:' + err);
    }
}
```

I want to use a button to get the trending movies info, so, I have this code in my page.tsx file:

```
'use client';
[imports...]

export default function Home() {
    interface MovieInfo {
        title: string;
        adult: boolean;
        original_language: string;
        overview: string;
        poster_path: string;
        vote_average: number;
        vote_count: number;
    }
    const [moviesInfo, setMoviesInfo] = useState<{}>({});

    async function getTrending(): Promise<void>{
        try {
            const info = await getTrendMovies();
            setMoviesInfo(info); //Here is where I'm getting the title error
      
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <NavigationBar/>
            <MovieCard info={moviesInfo} />
            <Button onClick={() => getTrending()}>
                Generate
            </Button>
        </>
    
    );
}
```

I need to save the info to create cards. The console.log(data) from the movies.ts is working well and prints the array with the info, but now that I want to save it into 'info' using useState, I'm getting that error and sincerely don't know what to do

I have read a lot of documentation but not getting any useful information.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed the return statement.

```
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('error:' + err);
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-a63xvf